# Can only make one GET request without error: "Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, restify

I want my http server to return some json returned from a async function. I've managed to make it work, but it only works once, then it throws: "Can't set headers after they are sent." error.

here is the following code:

```
var server = restify.createServer();

server.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    feed("dilma",[]);
    eventEmitter.on('retorno', function(retorno){   
        res.send(retorno);
    });
});

server.on("listening", function() {
   console.log("server running!");
});

server.listen(7171);
```

feed function:

```
var feed = function headLinesBySite(word, l) {
    if (!Array.isArray(l)) {
        console.log("por favor passe um array");
        return false;
    }
    if (l !== []) {
        links = l;
    }
    links = ["http://www.estadao.com.br/", "http://atarde.uol.com.br/"];
    var teste = 0;
    var final = [];
    for (i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        findHeadlines(links[i], word.toLowerCase(), function(r, url) {
            final.push({
                url: url,
                manchetes: r
            });
            //console.log(url+" - "+r);
            teste++;
            console.log((teste / links.length) * 100 + "%");
            if (teste === links.length) {
                console.log("Concluído!");
                console.log(final);
                eventEmitter.emit('retorno', final);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

findHeadlines function:

```
var findHeadlines = function findHeadlines(url, word, cb) {
    request(url, {
        timeout: 1000
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
            texto = [];
            var retorno = [];
            b = $('body').text().toLowerCase();
            c = b.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            texto = c.split("¬");
            for (var i = texto.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (texto[i].search(word) !== -1 && texto[i].length < 100) {
                    //console.log(texto[i]);
                    retorno.push("+" + texto[i] + "+");
                }
            }
            cb(retorno, url);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
            cb([], url);
        }
    });
};
```

The first time I call localhost/7171 I get the info, but after that, any GET request throws : "Can't set headers after they are sent.". I've read some similar questions about this same error but none of them helped me fix it... I just want to make the GET request wait for the async return of the feed function... Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
eventEmitter.on('retorno', function(retorno){   
    res.send(retorno);
});
```

you are subscribing to the `retorno` event, but you never unsubscribe. Hence, if the event is raised a second time, the old route handler runs `res.send` again - but now on an already closed connection.

Change `on` to `once` and the problem *might* be gone. For more details one would have to have a closer look at your entire code.

Hope this helps.

With subscribing and unsubscribing I mean that subscribing is like saying "From now on, I want to get notified when event X happens". This is valid until you say that you aren't interested any more (i.e., you unsubscribe). `on` is the equivalent of `subscribe`, usually you have to use `removeListener` to `unsubscribe`.

If you use `once`, you are effectively saying that you are subscribing, but only until the event has happened a single time - and then you would like to unsubscribe automatically. That's why it works then :-)

Comment: edited and added the whole code, i will try to use once and post the results!

Comment: Could you please make a brief explanation of subscribing and unsubscribing of events? The "once" has worked! Thank you so much! waiting the 10 required minutes to green(accept) your answer!

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe this will help you :-)